# Hot to change : to = or viceversa in FloatProperty declare by bpy.app.version statement?

Tags: python, properties

The transition from blender 2.79 to 2.8x changed many bees, so I was thinking of making the scripts compatible with all 2 versions through various if statements.
So at the time of the declaration of a FloatProperty, for example, in Blender 2.79 it looks like this:

```
my_float = FloatProperty()
```

in Blender 2.8x it looks like this:

```
my_float: FloatProperty()
```

Instinctively I would do:

```
if bpy.app.version > (2,8,0):

    my_float: bpy.props.FloatProperty()

else:

    my_float: bpy.props.FloatProperty()
```

But I have many things to change, and I was wondering how we could simply use a variable, which takes on something like this

```
if bpy.app.version > (2,8,0):
    #dec= :
else:
    #dec= =
```

so:

```
my_float dec FloatProperty()
```

I understand that this example is ridiculous, but I would like to understand more how you can do such a thing correctly, if possible.

Comment: It would be better to make separate scripts.
If you want to know other ways look at this question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133457/is-there-a-better-way-to-make-addon-working-on-both-blender-2-80-and-2-79

Comment: Very exact the topic you reported, I know it well, in fact at the moment I have 2 scripts that use the bees of the 2 versions, so 1 works on 2.79 and the other on 2.8x, but it is a pretty frustrating practice having to update 2 scripts , I wanted to understand if a question like mine was feasible