# How should I structure my Addon for maximum Blender version compatibility?

Tags: python

My Addon queries **a lot** of data within Blender (like which Render Engine does the current .blend file use or is Freestyle drawing enabled...). Now, I'm aware that I would have to update the Addon with future Blender releases as new "queryable" data might be added or prior data might be deleted. But how should I structure those queries so it works best with future releases? I would like to avoid that the Addon crashes when used with a new Blender version which I didn't yet update the Addon for.

My current query structure is as follows. I have multiple query functions which query different parts of Blender. These functions return a list with tuples as values. The tuples contain the queried data result and other info. Example code:

```
def query_properties():
    scene = bpy.context.scene

    query_properties = [
        (icon, scene, location, scene.render.engine),
        ...
    ]

    return query_properties
```

My ideas so far are:

1. Within my query functions I check if the queries will yield a result (perhaps via if statements or try/except). If not I will skip them to avoid crashing. In my head this means I would have to surround **every** query with said existence check (or use some sort of verify_function).
2. Within my query functions I check for the currently used Blender version and only execute queries (like bpy.data.scenes[scene].render.engine) that will not fail with said Blender version. This means that the Addon won't work with new Blender versions if I don't update it and I will have a lot of duplicate code which feels wrong.

Maybe my initial structure is already lacking? How would you solve this issue?

I hope I could illustrate my issue well enough. If not I'm happy to give more info. Your help will be highly appreciated!

EDIT: Applied batFINGER's suggestion.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133457/is-there-a-better-way-to-make-addon-working-on-both-blender-2-80-and-2-79

Comment: True, that doesn't make much sense. Thanks for pointing it out!